# Css style stays the same even though class associated with this style is removed

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am pretty new to HTML, CSS and Javascript, So I hope you guys can help me. This is my Code so far (I created this code also on JSFiddle so you guys can test it: https://jsfiddle.net/veka33/f80sbqrc/1/ - the button there is placed a little bit weird even though in the browser it looks fine):

```
1. HTML-file

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 200px;">
        <div class="project showScroll" id="project1" onclick="showProject('1')">
            <p style="font-size: 30px;">1. Projekt</p>
            <button class="custom_button" id="close1" onclick="hideProject('1')"><i class="material-icons">close_fullscreen</i></button>
            <div id="projectText1" class="prjText">
                <p>Here is the information</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project showScroll" id="project2" onclick="showProject('2')">
            <p style="font-size: 30px;">2. Projekt</p>
            <button class="custom_button" id="close2" onclick="hideProject('2')"><i class="material-icons">close_fullscreen</i></button>
            <div id="projectText2" class="prjText">
                <p>Here is the information</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

2. CSS-file

body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: auto;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 250px;
}

.project {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(0, 153, 51);
    margin: 100px 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100px;
    transition: width 2s,
                padding-left 2s,
                height 2s;
    will-change: width, padding-left, height;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.project.isVisible {
    width: 650px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.project.isVisible.expand {
    width: 80%;
    height: 500px;
}

.prjText {
    position: relative;
    left: -27px;
    top: -50px;
    height: 0px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: height 2s,
                color 0s,
                background-color 0s;
    will-change: height, color, background-color;
}

.prjText.info_expand {
    height: 400px;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}

.custom_button {
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(0, 153, 51);
    opacity: 0;
    left: 650px;
    top: 25px;
    position: absolute; 
    transition: opacity 2s,
                left 2s;
    will-change: opacity, left;
}


.custom_button.icon_expand {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 995px;
}

3. Js-file

// 1. Scroll animation
// Detect request animation frame
var scroll = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
             // IE Fallback
             function(callback){ window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60)};
var elementsToShow = document.querySelectorAll('.showScroll'); 

function loop() {

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elementsToShow, function(element){
      if (isElementInViewport(element)) {
        element.classList.add('isVisible');
      } else {
        // element.classList.remove('isVisible');
      }
    });

    scroll(loop);
}

// Call the loop for the first time
loop();

// Helper function from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7557433/274826
function isElementInViewport(el) {
  // special bonus for those using jQuery
  if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
    el = el[0];
  }
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    (rect.top <= 0
      && rect.bottom >= 0)
    ||
    (rect.bottom >= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight))
    ||
    (rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight))
  );
}

// 2. Show and hide Projects

function showProject(no){
    var prj = "project" + no;
    var element = document.getElementById(prj);
    element.classList.add("expand");
    document.getElementById(("projectText"+no)).classList.add("info_expand");
    document.getElementById(("close"+no)).classList.add("icon_expand");
}

function hideProject(no){
    var prj = "project" + no;
    var element = document.getElementById(prj);
    element.classList.remove("expand");
    document.getElementById(("projectText"+no)).classList.remove("info_expand");
    document.getElementById(("close"+no)).classList.remove("icon_expand");
}
```

My problem is that the style is changed when I click on the divs with the id 'project1' and 'project2' since I add three classes ('.expand','.info_expand','.icon_expand') to these divs and objects inside the divs with a different style. These classes are removed with the java function 'hideProject()'. However, the style stays the same even though the classes the style is based on is removed. I really don't get how this could happen? I hope you guys can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have nested onclick events, the inner onclick also triggers the parent onclick event (propagation).

You can pass the event from the html to the function and just call

`event.stopPropagation()`

So that the event will only run itself and not propagate the click event up the chain.

Here's a working example :

https://jsfiddle.net/twxn48oL/

Comment: Thanks for the great and fast answer! I knew that there was an easy solution for this problem. So, I learned something new for the future.

Comment: Please select this as the answer if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Because your `Button` is inside the `DIV`

When you click on button, you are also clicking on `DIV` and `DIV` execute `showProject`

you should define your button in HTML out side of `DIV` like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 200px;">
        <div class="project showScroll" id="project1" onclick="showProject('1')">
            <p style="font-size: 30px;">1. Projekt</p>
            <div id="projectText1" class="prjText">
                <p>Here is the information</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="custom_button" id="close1" onclick="hideProject('1')"><i class="material-icons">close_fullscreen</i></button>


        <div class="project showScroll" id="project2" onclick="showProject('2')">
            <p style="font-size: 30px;">2. Projekt</p>
            <div id="projectText2" class="prjText">
                <p>Here is the information</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="custom_button" id="close2" onclick="hideProject('2')"><i class="material-icons">close_fullscreen</i></button>

    </div>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Both solutions work fine for me. However, the first one keeps the alignment of the elements so I prefer this one. But you also helped me, thanks!